# Javascript within a form to populate 6 fields with days of the week, based on an initial value set in a drop-down list

Tags: javascript

My apologies if this has been previously addressed; I was unable to find a solution already described.

I should preempt my question by stating that I am new to coding JS.

I am trying to set JavaScript within a form to populate 6 fields with days of the week, based on an initial value set in a drop-down list.

Pseudo-code:

```
Field 0 Drop-down list value selected by user is 'Tuesday'
Field 1 populates to 'Wednesday'
Field 2 populates to 'Thursday'
Field 3 populates to 'Friday'
Field 4 populates to 'Saturday'
Field 5 populates to 'Sunday'
Field 6 populates to 'Monday'
```

Comment: Please post more information.  Show us the HTML you have created and describe in more detail what you want to accomplish using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a <strike>five</strike> ten minute break, so here's my jQuery solution (assuming you are open to its use):

#### HTML

```
<select id="day0"></select><br />
<input id="day1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="day2" type="text" /><br />
<input id="day3" type="text" /><br />
<input id="day4" type="text" /><br />
<input id="day5" type="text" /><br />
<input id="day6" type="text" /><br />
```

#### JS:

```
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

function update(sel) {
    var start = parseInt($(sel).val());
    for (var i = 1; i <= days.length; i++) {
        $('#day' + i).val(days[(i + start) % 7]);                            
    }   
}

$(function() {
    // Find the select list
    var $sel = $('#day0');
    // Populate it with values from the 'days' array
    $.each(days, function(i, v) {
        $('<option value="' + i + '">' + v + '</option>').appendTo($sel);
    });
    // Hook up the 'update' function to run every time the
    // selected option is changed
    $sel.change(function() { 
        update(this);
    });
    // Force an initial update of the fields
    update($sel);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9GxF/2)**

Answer (score -2):

Some snippet:

HTML

```
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

Javascript

```
var days = {
    v0 : 'Tuesday',
    v1 : 'Wednesday',
    v2 : 'Thursday',
    v3 : 'Friday',
    v4 : 'Saturday',
    v5 : 'Sunday',
    v6 : 'Monday'
};

var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
for(index in days) {
    dropdown.options[dropdown.options.length] = new Option(days[index], index);
}
```

Comment: Remember to use 'var' even in for loops, or when defining any new variable to avoid leaking into the global scope or over writing previous global variables.

Comment: Code to generate the drop-down values was not the goal here.